# Programatically read content from terminal emulator

Tags: c#, automation

I'm trying to automate some operations in Mainframe. For that I made a C# program that connects to Mainframe using terminal emulator wc3270 and send keys to it.

This part works fine.

My problem is that I need to read the content displayed in terminal emulator screen so I can take better decisions about which keys I'll send to it.

How could I do it? I didn't find out any API that would let me do it.

Thanks.

Comment: How are you sending data to it such that reading from it isn't immediately obvious?  There are usually opposites of operations defined.

Comment: I'm using the SendKeys function from Windows (http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.windows.forms.sendkeys.sendwait%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using IBM personal communication tools: 
http://www-03.ibm.com/software/products/en/pcomm

Together with the C# EHLLAPI wrapper, URL to example: 
https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9615/Using-EHLLAPI-in-C

To find out the session key for the emulator, you can use handle.exe from Windows Sysinternals

Code that im using for handle:

```
public String getSessionKey(String pid)
    {
        Process p = new Process();
        p.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo()
        {
            UseShellExecute = false,
            CreateNoWindow = true,
            WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden,
            FileName = "cmd.exe",
            Arguments = "/C C:\\handle.exe -a -p " + pid,
            RedirectStandardError = true,
            RedirectStandardOutput = true
        };
        p.Start();

        String str = (p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd());
        String[] arr = str.Split('\n');

        foreach (String s in arr)
        {
            if (s.Contains("Owned"))
            {
                return s.Substring(s.Length - 3, 1);
            }
        }

        return "";
    }
```